# Out of memory exception thrown on basic Doctrine MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

I have about 60k documents in my database and I cannot query for them.  The only way I have been able to successfully retrieve them is with the hydrate(false) option.

I have tried both:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
    $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('BConwayWebsiteBundle:Business')
        ->eagerCursor(true);
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->execute();
```

and

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
    $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('BConwayWebsiteBundle:Business');
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->execute();
```

If I dump $results->isInitialized() it is false.  I believe that is because I have not utilized it yet at that point.  Any accesing I try to do causes the memory issue though.  Even something as basic as $results->count().

```
[2013-10-01 23:54:55] doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"find":true,"query":[],"fields":[],"db":"ClosedForTheHoliday","collection":"businesses"} [] []
[2013-10-01 23:54:55] doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"limit":true,"limitNum":null,"query":[],"fields":[]} [] []
[2013-10-01 23:54:55] doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"skip":true,"skipNum":null,"query":[],"fields":[]} [] []
[2013-10-01 23:54:55] doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"sort":true,"sortFields":[],"query":[],"fields":[]} [] []
[2013-10-01 23:54:56] emergency.EMERGENCY: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) {"type":1,"file":"/media/sf_sites/cfth_com/vendor/doctrine/mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Cursor.php","line":237} []
```

UPDATE: If I limit my results to 2000, it works.  Furthermore, if I select only the two fields that I am going to use after the query, I can limit it to 15000 and have success.  When I limit it to 2000 the dev debug bar says that the query used 120MB of memory.  I need to be able to iterate through all of the results, and it cannot be paginated.  It seems like that should be possible without having 100MB+ queries...

Answer (score 0):

I only needed distinct data from two fields, so this is what I ended up doing:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();

// Get organization name from all businesses (distinct)
$organizations = $dm->createQueryBuilder('BConwayWebsiteBundle:Business')
    ->distinct('organization')
    ->getQuery()
    ->toArray();

// Get business name from all businesses (distinct)
$names = $dm->createQueryBuilder('BConwayWebsiteBundle:Business')
    ->field('organization')->equals('')
    ->field('organization')->equals(null)
    ->distinct('name')
    ->getQuery()
    ->toArray();

// Create new array from results of both queries
$businesses = array_merge($organizations, $names);

// Filter out any null or empty values
$businesses = array_filter($businesses, function($item) {
    return (!is_null($item) && strlen($item) > 0);
});

// Filter out any duplicates
array_unique($businesses);

// Sort array case-insensitive
sort($businesses, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Doctrine MongoDB ODM is a persistence manager (likewise with Doctrine ORM 2.x for relational databases), references to hydrated objects are stored internally and will not be recovered by PHP's garbage collection as easily as if you were iterating over non-hydrated array results that quickly leave scope.

For any batch operations in Doctrine, you'll want to either periodically `clear()` the object manager of all managed objects, or manually `detach()` individual objects. A periodic `clear()` would probably be easiest in your case, as you could do it every X iterations through the results. You can find some code examples and a discussion of this solution in [this blog post](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html). Although it's written from the perspective of the ORM and its EntityManager class, ODM's DocumentManager implements the same ObjectManager interface from the Doctrine Common library, which is where you'll find the `detach()` and `clear()` methods.